# Making a Tachometer using LED and Laser?

Tags: arduino, measurement, encoder, speed

I am making a tachometer to measure speed of a wheel using a LED and Laser.

The phenomena is that when Ray of Laser is shown on LED , 0.5 V are produced. I will connect a Schmitt trigger (made using LM741). The output of the trigger will be read using the interrupt pin of Uno. And using some calculation i will measure the rpm.

The problem is that when i connect the Led in Pull up configuration as shown in figure. The LED voltage does not change with laser. I am using Arduino Uno to Read Analog Values.

```
    ////           + GROUND                                 +5 V   DC       
    ////           |                                        |  
    ////           <                                        < 
    ////           > 220 ohm resistor                       > 100K ohm resistor
    ////           <                                        <      
    ////           |                                        |  
    ////           |                                        |------Analog Read
    ////         -----                                    -----
    ////          / \    >>Laser >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>  / \   LED 
    ////         -----                                    -----
    ////           |                                        |
    ////           |                                        |
    ////           + +5V DC                                  +  Ground
```

I think that this method of LEd and laser is non-practical. Is their any other way that can help me to make tachometer?

Comment: You *could* try using an actual photosensor rather than trying to use an LED as a photosensor. LEDs make pretty horrible sensors. If you insist, look up transimpedance amplifiers used for PD front ends (anything written by Phil Hobbs is good).

Comment: something like this http://www.circuitstoday.com/tachometer-using-arduino

Comment: 1.) wrong "color" laser and LED?  2.) not enough photocurrent; Use your DMM to measure the short circuit current from the LED.  (I'd guess something in the uA range... what sort of voltage drop will you get?... perhaps a bigger resistor.)

Comment: After realizing that LED as horrible sensor.  I have decided to measure RMP using a Hall Sensor A3144.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold The current is so low that when i connect it with Op-Amp, the LED output voltage has no effect in the circuit. The current in uA is totally dissipated.